# If statement conditions being ignored and going straight to else no matter what you input

Tags: python

I'm somewhat new to Python and I was creating a test program for a project, which is a game where you have to guess the definitions of certain Python phrases. I got the first half working, but the second half has issues. It's supposed to randomly choose a definition from a tuple, and ask you to input the correct word. However, no matter what word it is, it always goes to the else statement where you inputted a wrong answer. I've tried a lot of things, changing around the parentheses,  the variables, and everything inbetween.
This is the second half that's having issues:
(variables are defined at the top, which isn't included)

```
while (len(wordPool) >= 1):
  answer = input(random.choice(question) + " What word is that? ")
  if question == vocabularyDefinitions[0] and answer == "List":
        print("You got it right! That is a list!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[1]  and answer == "Tuple":
        print("That is correct! That is a tuple!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[2] and answer == "Datetime":
        print("Nice job! That is the datetime module!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[3] and answer == "Random":
        print("That's right! That is in fact the random module!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[4] and answer == "Include":
        print("Yep, that's the include function! Well done!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[5] and answer == "Parameter":
        print("That is a parameter, keep it up!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[6] and answer == "Index":
        print("You must know your stuff! That's an index alright.")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[7] and answer == "Len":
        print("This congratulatory message says well done!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[8] and answer == "Append":
        print("You have a knack at this don't you? Keep going!")
        score +=1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[9] and answer == "Insert":
        print("Yes! You answered correctly!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1 
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[10] and answer == "Remove":
        print("I definitely won't remove you after that correct answer! Which was remove by the way.")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[11] and answer == "Iterate":
        print("That was in fact the definition of iterate in Python!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[12] and answer == "Loop":
        print("It's highly unlikely the while loop will show you this message again, but if it does, consider yourself lucky!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif question == vocabularyDefinitions[13] and answer == "Element":
        print("The index number of this word is the same as the atomic number for Aluminum. The more you know!")
        score += 1
        totalAttempts += 1
  elif (answer == "End"):
        break
  else:
        print("Whoops! That wasn't the right answer!")
        wrongAnswer += 1

print(str.format("The game is over, and got {} questions right, {} questions wrong, and your total attempts was {}.",score,wrongAnswer,totalAttempts))
```

What could I add/remove so that the if/elif statements aren't ignored in your input?

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ that `question` comes directly from `vocabularyDefinitions`? It's possible that it's slightly different, thus not comparing properly.

Comment: I made the question variable by simply saying that its equal to vocabularyDefinitions. I didn't want to use the latter variable in the if/elif's because it would be weird to use the same variable equaling to itself.

Comment: Try assigning `question = random.choice(vocabularyDefinitions)`, right at the start of the `while` loop. This way, you can treat it as the 'chosen question', and then compare it to where it came from.

Comment: Weirdly, when I do that and do the randomization, The definition doesnt even appear, and only the string part of the input appears. It's familiar to a similar tactic I did before, where the only difference was me putting the question assignment above the while loop, and when I did that the definition was simply a letter from the word "question".

Comment: Please show how you assign `vocabulary Definitions` and `question`. That's where the problem is, so we can't help you unless you show it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could assume since the variable were not included in the post, "question" is an iterable. (so for simplicity, let's say question is a list)

Hence you did...

```
answer = input(random.choice(question) + " What word is that? ")
```

Why the comparison between a list and a string?

```
question == vocabularyDefinitions[0]
```

Comment: This seems like a question, not an answer.

Comment: @Barmar My fault.  I was trying to point out to the OP that the comparison might be between 2 different data types. Hence the reason none of the if/elif condition is never reached.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).